# memcpy and pointers

Tags: c, memcpy

I am confuse on how to read the pointers copied in an array using memcpy.
Following is what I have tried, but does not work.

Basically, I have allocated block of memory in which I am copying pointers similar to array fashion, but during retrial it is not working. While this works with basic data types properly

I want to store anything in the `element` block, It can be either `integers` or `pointers`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INDEX(x)  ((char *)elements + (sizeof(int*) * (x)))
int size = 10;

void f2_int_ptr() {    
    int i = 0;
    void *elements = (void*)malloc(size * sizeof(int*));
    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) { 
       int *v = ( int *) malloc ( sizeof(int));
       memcpy ( v, &i, sizeof ( int ));


       memcpy ( INDEX(i) , v,  sizeof (int*));
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) { 
        int *v = (int*)0;
        memcpy ( v, INDEX(i), sizeof(int *));
        printf ( "%d\n", *v );
    }
}
void f1_int() {
    int i = 0;
    void *elements = (void*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) { 
       memcpy ( INDEX(i) , &i,  sizeof (int));
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) { 
        int v;
        memcpy ( &v, INDEX(i), sizeof ( int ));
        printf ( "%d\n", v );
    }
}
int main(){
    f1_int();
    f2_int_ptr();
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code `f1_int` works fine but `f2_int_ptr` does not work.

Comment: Note: All this typecasting to and from `void *` (and the macro) is not making your code pretty nasty.  Is there any reason you're using `void *` everywhere?

Comment: This works for all basic types, but not working only for pointers.

Comment: You should try to clarify your code if you intend it to be read. C being a hoax (http://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/unix-hoax.html) is not an argument to code that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`f2_int_ptr()` needs to become this:

```
void f2_int_ptr() {
    int i = 0;
    void *elements = malloc(size * sizeof(int*));

    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) { 
       int *v = malloc ( sizeof(int));
       memcpy ( v, &i, sizeof ( int ));
       memcpy ( INDEX(i) , &v,  sizeof (int*));
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        int *v;
        memcpy ( &v, INDEX(i), sizeof(int *));
        printf ( "%d\n", *v );
    }
}
```

Note the subtle changes to the `memcpy()` arguments.

*Note: I really, really, really, wouldn't write code like this!  It's incredibly difficult to follow.*

Comment: If i use pointer-to-pointer then I have to make sure always that elements going into the block is always allocated, I cannot have elements from the stack.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, I agree that this is not good code, but with your solution, It means I have to keep to different approaches for copy and retrieval for basic type and pointer type.

Comment: @Avinash: Basic types and pointer types are fundamentally different.  It's still not clear why you wish to be able to treat them the same.  What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am trying to write a stl vector in C, and I could do it if client allocating memory on the heap and pass as an element to me. But I want it to work with basic datatype and there should not be special way to pass variables on the stack or heap variables.

Comment: there is way to do this using MACROS but i was looking for option which avoid MACROS.

Answer (score 0):

Code is very ugly, so I dont even know how it should works but:
Why are u using &v here:

```
memcpy ( &v, INDEX(i), sizeof ( int ));
```

v is pointer itself:

```
int *v = (int*)0;
```

Comment: It dumps without that. I wanted to read from the array, I am not sure how to do that and array has pointer copied.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing the pointers in the elemnts, I think the final memcpy needs to use &v to copy the element to the pointer v. Similar to v=elements[i].

```
void f2_int_ptr() {    
    int i = 0;
    void *elements = (void*)malloc(size * sizeof(int*));
    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) { 
       int *v = ( int *) malloc ( sizeof(int));
       memcpy ( v, &i, sizeof ( int *));


       memcpy ( INDEX(i) , &v,  sizeof (int*));
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) { 
        int *v = (int *)0;
        memcpy ( &v, INDEX(i), sizeof(int *));
        printf ( "%d\n", *v );
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. With the edit I think I see what you are trying to do, (Copy the pointer into elements.) so I've updated.

Comment: This will also dump, I guess I need to allocate the v before getting element back.

Comment: Would't have thought you needed to as you already have the original alloc.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Guys, it worked finally.
i guess i have not allocated the space where to copy memcpy.

```
void f2_int_ptr() {    
    int i = 0;
    void *elements = (void*)malloc(size * sizeof(int*));
    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) { 
       int *v = ( int *) malloc ( sizeof(int));
       memcpy ( v, &i, sizeof ( int ));

       memcpy ( INDEX(i) , v,  sizeof (int*));
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) { 
        int *v = ( int *) malloc (sizeof(int*));
        memcpy ( v, INDEX(i), sizeof(int*));
        printf ( "%d\n", *v );
    }
}
```

Comment: because you have a memory leak.  You are not freeing `v` in the first or second loop.  Also, you are storing `int` values in `elements`, not `int *`.  See my answer.